# CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion limitations

Tags: ios, ios7, ibeacon

In the Apple documentation for `startMonitoringForRegion` method there is this text:

> An app can register up to 20 regions at a time. In order to report region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service requires network connectivity.

Do this 20 regions are only for this app or globally?

Comment: Do my eyes deceive me, or does your quote start with the words "an app"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 20 regions per app. I don't know if there's a top number globally (i.e. for the device).